# .htaccess not working for PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess does not respond to RewriteRules. I have created a .htaccess file at the root of my project, and filled it with the below RewriteConditions

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)& index.php?url=1 [NC, L]
```

But I get false instead of true when I execute the below code in my index.php

```
<?php
 var_dump(isset($_GET["url"]));
```

Below is what I have in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I run my server from my folder located in my Home directory rather than `/var/www/html`

Also, when I access any part of the site `localhost:8000/fishes`, it still loads the `index.php` with `false` displaying

I have been battling this but to no avail, please help guys, what could I be doing wrong.

Comment: Is there in ampersand in the requested URL? You probably want `url=$1` instead of `url=1`.

Comment: @chris85 no, not really, what I want to do is just get the number 1 and display, I was using it to test

Comment: If there isn't an ampersand than this `^(.+)&` won't match. If you don't care about found value than you dont need the `()`.

Comment: @chris85, oh, thanks, I just added the ampersand, still does not work

Comment: Does the rewrite work at all?

Comment: @mrun I can't tell, when I access any part of the site localhost:8000/fishes, it still loads the index.php with false displaying

Comment: what happens if you put random text in `.htaccess?` You should get `500 Internal server error`

Comment: @InigoFlores nothing happens, it just stares at me with the same false...

Comment: Please post your VirtualHost config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is because I am running PHP outside of apache /var/www/ directory, apparently if I want it to work outside there I will have to set it from`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule (.+) index.php?url=1 [NC, L]
```

---

Also, replace your `Directory /` definition with the following:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require All Granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache.

---

Make your home folder executable by apache. I assume you are using linux:

```
chmod a+x /home/myhome
```

Comment: No luck, I wonder what the problem could be, I have been on this since lunch

Comment: Try the new set of Options as per edit: `-MultiViews`

Comment: Okay, thanks Inigo Flores, alot, after creating a virtual host and dumping my files under /var/www/dev.com/public_hmtl, the .htaccess starts working, but not outside of that directory